# Can't mine the genesis block of an PoS + mn coin

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

I am studying blockchain and I am trying to mine the genesis block of an crypto source.

The source I have is an PoS + masternode source. Of course there is PoW in it to mine the first blocks.

So I generated the genesis hash and merkle root. The daemon boots up and everything works. But the moment I use the "setgenerate true" or "getblocktemplate" commands nothing happens. The genesis block can't be mined.

The "getblocktemplate" returns "Out of memory (code -7)"
Debug.log shows:

```
2019-01-21 16:23:42 ERROR: CheckTransaction() : txout.nValue negative
2019-01-21 16:23:42 ERROR: CheckBlock() : CheckTransaction failed
2019-01-21 16:23:42 CreateNewBlock() : TestBlockValidity failed
2019-01-21 16:23:42 CreateNewBlock: Failed to detect masternode to pay
2019-01-21 16:23:42 CreateNewBlock(): total size 1000
```

I disabled the masternode enforcement sporks

Is there anyone who experienced something like this or can help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

The genesis block doesn't actually require mining. You can create it as whatever you want as long as it follows the serialisation of your protocol. Genesis blocks tend to follow slightly different rules to normal blocks and so often do not pass validation under normal circumstances. 
[Here](https://github.com/Team-Hycon/hycon-core/blob/master/src/common/blockGenesis.ts) is how we handle the genesis block in our code-base. It has slightly different rules to how we handle [other blocks](https://github.com/Team-Hycon/hycon-core/blob/master/src/common/block.ts). 
All a block needs is a block to point backwards to. So as long as you have some previous hash new blocks should be able to be formed on top of your genesis block.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try Bitshares or Steem code and see how the mining goes. You can use the TEST mode in either one to starting creating / mining blocks from the Genesis block.